# Wordpress: Objetos post y user con el mismo ID

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

El proyecto en el que estamos trabajando requiere asignar una taxonomia personalizada a los usuarios que a su vez se relacionan a un custom post type, es decir, queremos etiquetar posts y usuarios con el mismo custom term.

El problema viene que el objeto user genera ids independientemente de los posts, es decir, existe el riesgo de que un usuario tenga el mismo id que un post con lo que las relationship de las taxonomias no serviría de nada.

La pregunta: ¿existe la posibilidad, ya sea por sql o vía callback de wp, de que los usuarios y los posts tengan en conjunto un único id? Es decir, que no se solapen.

Gracias por adelantado por vuestra atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes establecer un umbral para cada tipo de cosas. Por ejemplo, los usuarios podrían comenzar a partir del ID 1000000. siendo el primero el ID 1000001.

Te propongo hacer esto con un pequeño hack. Primero abre tu BD mysql. Tenes que ir a la tabla xx_USERS. Revisa tu ultimo ID de usuario. Modificalo manualmente con el valor 1000000.

A partir de ese momento Wordpress va a crear a los usuarios desde el ID indicado manualmente.

[image: Ejemplo de la modificacion de ID en Wordpress]

PD: Lo mismo se puede realizar con los POST. Aunque con los post es mas complejos porque el ID de los post es compartido con las imagenes y otro tipo de contenido.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias, esto soluciona el problema. Hay que tener en cuenta que, es poco probable pero existe la posibilidad, se superen el número de usuarios/post de sus respectivos rangos de ID's y se solapen. De todas maneras esta es la mejor solución sin duda.